# Seeing black lines in my render using Cycles with GPU compute

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

So I'm doing the blender donut tutorial by blender guru and im at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTxBrjN1ugA&feature=emb_rel_end
whenever I render with Cycles and GPU compute I get these strange black lines:

[image]

For some reason when I do it with CPU it doesnt show them and CPU rendering is for some reason way faster than GPU compute and I get this clean image:

[image]

My GPU is an AMD RX460 and yes I have updated drivers and no the GPU compute option isnt grayed out.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a bug, which is currently being dealt with [here](https://developer.blender.org/T77095)

Comment: Try to update your graphics driver. It appears that this issue doesn't occur with the most recent ones. See bug report: https://developer.blender.org/T77095